# Add a url parameter to get more results

Tags: url, web-scraping

I would like to be able to modify the parameters of this page in order to get more than 100 results. Is there a way to discover the correct parameter and modify accordingly the url?

```
url = https://jobs.smartrecruiters.com
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max results is set to 100 no mater what you do , This is how they structured it . You can use this Url that will return back a Json Object with those 100 results :

```
https://jobs.smartrecruiters.com/sr-jobs/search?keyword={search_word_here}&limit=100
```